# Probability of a coin falling in a grid without touching boundary.

Tags: probability

> A coin of diameter $1"$ is allowed to fall on table.  There is a large $2\times 2$ grid covering the table.  What is the probability that the coin will fall in grid without touching a line of the grid?

If four coins are kept fitting a particular grid and touching the boundary of the grid,  a $1"\times 1"$ small square is formed within by connecting the centers.  Now, if the centre of coin lies within that square, then the case will be satisfied.

So, the probability is:

$$\frac{\text{Area of $ 1"\times1"$ square }}{\text{Area of a grid }}$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}$$

Is there any simpler approach to this problem?

Comment: What is a "nervous" grid?

Comment: @David sorry,  *numerous*

Comment: This seems very vague.  What does "numerous" mean in this context?  Do you just mean that the table top is tiled with a $2\times 2$ square lattice?

Comment: @lulu... Yes...

Comment: FWIW Your answer is exactly how I would do it ... I think it's plenty rigorous, and about as simple as you can get.

Comment: I think in order to be completely rigorous you need to state a probability distribution for throwing the coin. I would focus on the center of the coin. // Suppose we look at just one grid square. Center of coin is chosen according to a uniform distribution on the square. In what region $A$ can the center of the coin fall so that it does not touch a side? Answer is area of $A$ divided by area of square.

Comment: Assuming I understand your question properly, the line of reasoning you present is valid.  And you want a *simpler* one?  The one you present is pretty simple!